# "Are you the one who called?" or "Are you the one that called?"

Tags: word-choice, pronouns, word-in-context

How does one decide whether to use *who* or *that*? In the title example:

1. The correct pronoun is *who*.
2. The correct pronoun is *that*.
3. Either is correct. They're interchangeable.
4. It depends on the context.

Comment: More people are likely to use *who* in written English, but in spoken English *that* is common.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are you the **one** *who* called...
>
> Are you the **one** *that* called ...

Though normally a human antecedent is followed by *who*, yet in some cases *that* is also accepted. Both of these sentences quoted above are correct.

---

> Normally use **"who"** as the relative pronoun following a human antecedent and **"that"** (or **"which"**) following an inanimate antecedent.
>
> Either **"who"** or **"that"** may be used when the antecedent is animate but not human, or when the antecedent is human but representative of a class or is an indefinite pronoun.
>
> **Example -**
>
> **a white poodle** *that* sported a red hair bow. (antecedent is animate but not human)
>
> **a baby** *that* cries in unsocial hours. (antecedent is human but representative of a class)
>
> **a fellow** *that* sells a bracelet is not necessarily interested in people. (antecedent is human but representative of a class)
>
> it was an obvious rebuff, and **one** *that* hurt Benn very deep. (antecedent is an indefinite pronoun)

<sub>From The New Fowler's Modern English Usage - R. W. Burchfield page no. 773</sub>

Comment: In other words, are only the examples from this source, or all the material under the horizontal rule, or everything in your answer?

Comment: Your answer (or source) also does not address usage difference between spoken and written English.

Comment: @pazzo All texts under horizontal line is from the book. I have edited my answer to expand the abbreviated name of the book, and now it says the full name of the book. And also the author's name. Yes, it doesn't say anything about written/spoken English. I am not very sure about what is appropriate in what variety of English. So I skipped that part :-)

Comment: @pazzo, I don't believe the guidelines for written or spoken English would differ for the statement. However, I could be surprised to find written guidelines to be more formal. If someone knows this to be true, please share.